# Australian Vehicle or Car Brands, Models, Styles, and Specs API

Tags: data-request, api, cars, australia

I need to show Car Models and Specs on my Website. Similar to carsales.com.au search form. Does any one know an API to get these data? There's a lot of US APIs but no Australian APIs at all. There is one RedBook API. But is there any other cheaper options?

**I checked Following but no luck**

https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/

http://edmunds.mashery.com/

Comment: I assume you can't/won't simply scrape the data from carsales.com.au directly? (I can't seem to access the page at the moment, but it should be possible)

Comment: @BarryCarter We dont want to do that becuase 1) its illegal and 2) The website we are building is a public website.

Answer (score 0):

hmm, never needed information for a particular market. my recent project included diesel hatchbacks (starting from 2010 year of production) - no particular brand either, nor a narrow market.

I ended up acquiring the information i needed from a link posted in one of the questions here. from my humble experience with cars, there could be slight variations in the names of some vehicles - keep that in mind. I am linking to the [specs info source](https://www.car-database-api.com/vehicle-api-parameters) i recently used ( to the parameters page, so you could check out if they will do the job). You could download a free demo to see what the data bank has to offer.